# Why does controller need to add model on Binding Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In a Spring-Boot controller during user registration if there is a binding error my controller returns the user to the registration page but in my implementation the model seems to be missing.

For example I commonly see on [tutorials](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-security-user-registration-example-thymeleaf/)

```
    @PostMapping
public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserRegistrationDto userDto, 
                                  BindingResult result){

    User existing = userService.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    if (existing != null){
        result.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account registered with that email");
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userDto);
    return "redirect:/registration?success";
}
```

Which, if there are binding errors returns "registration"

My controller is very similar:

```
    @PostMapping("/user/register")
public String registerNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO,
                              BindingResult bindingResult,
                              Model model,
                              HttpServletRequest request,
                              Errors errors) {
    User existing = userService.findUserByEmail(registerUserDTO.getEmail());
    if (existing != null) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account with that Email");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    userService.createUser(registerUserDTO);
    return "redirect:/registration?success";
 }
}
```

However when I return "register" there is a binding error on the stack at what corresponds to my first thymeleaf tag relating to the object.

If I change the POST controller to add the model explicitly:

```
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute(registerUserDTO);
        return "register";
    }
```

Then it works, returning the page with the model and previously entered data.

> Why am I having to explicitly add the model to the return?

**UPDATE**

This does not work either:

```
    @PostMapping("/user/register")
public String registerNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO,
                              BindingResult bindingResult) {
    User existing = userService.findUserByEmail(registerUserDTO.getEmail());
    if (existing != null) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account with that Email");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
```

Comment: Because of your method signature. The `BindingResult` is the same as `Errors` and the `BindingResult` contains the model. IN your case you have 3 places containing the model and one of them is picked. So remove the `model` and `errors` attributes.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated question.

Comment: Add the exception/error you have. Judging from the `model.addAttribute` you're `@ModelAttribute` points to the wrong object (shouldn't be `user` but `registerUserDTO` as that is what `model.addAttribute` does it takes the classname.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks that worked. Let me know if my answer re tutorial is correct or was it because the tutorial had some other annotations prior to the get/post controllers?

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
    @PostMapping("/user/register")
    public String registerNewUser(@ModelAttribute("registerUserDTO") @Valid RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO,
                              BindingResult bindingResult) {
    User existing = userService.findUserByEmail(registerUserDTO.getEmail());
    if (existing != null) {
           bindingResult.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account with that Email");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    userService.createUser(registerUserDTO);
    return "redirect:/registration?success";
}
```

As M.Denium pointed out the @ModelAttribute name needed to be the same as the instance name of the backing object used in the GET controller. In my GET controller I had :

```
    @GetMapping("/user/register")
String registerForm(Model model) {
    RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO = new RegisterUserDTO();
    model.addAttribute(registerUserDTO);
    return "register";
}
```

So the @ModelAttribute needs to match, ie @ModelAttribute("***registerUserDTO***")

Comment: It doesn't need to be the same as the classname it has to match the name you decided to give it when rendering the form. So either change your `@GetMapping`  method to something like `model.addAttribute("user", new RegisterUserDTO())` and use the `user` as the name in your Thymeleaf form as well. The main point here is the names should match. It isn't an error in the tutorial as the `@ModelAttribute` annotated method uses the same name `@ModelAttribute("user")` if you omit the `user` part here it will use the name of the class. So the tutorial is perfectly fine.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Is the summary of the answer now correct?